# trying to use External Stylesheet from Google drive in Ebay Listing

Tags: css

I was creating ebay listing template and want to use/share stylesheet.css from my google drive in my ebay listing like we do it in Html Document (using external stylesheet).

I tried this code, but it didn't work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XAOJXHLKNveVRwRUowaWlRNzQ/view?usp=sharing">
```

Comment: Before asking solution, please say what issue you are facing?

Comment: https://community.ebay.com/t5/Archive-Selling/Right-way-to-make-an-ebay-listing-using-CSS-and-Javascript/m-p/19722086

Comment: @SyamPillai Hi, I have added the code I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Google drive does not support hot linking. Try some other service like Dropbox.

Comment: the file is not correctly hosted. check this link. http://www.komku.org/2013/08/how-to-host-javascript-or-css-files-on-google-drive.html

Answer (score 0):

It's because Google Drive does not provide you raw file content and if you check source of your link, you will find HTML instead of CSS file content.